# Do you need .PHONY if no prerequisites

Tags: makefile

When using make for just commands, do you then need to add .PHONY targets?

Note: I do not have a file called "all"

```
# Do I need this, if no prerequisites
.PHONY somecommands

# Taget with no prerequisites
somecommands:
    @echo hello
```

Answer (score 1):

`.PHONY` is needed when the target isn't a file.

This is the `Makefile`:

```
all:
    @echo DONE
```

Try to test:

```
$ make all                                                                                                                               
DONE
$ touch all
$ make
`all' is up to date.
```

Comment: exactly and this will work as long I do not have a file called "all"a. So PHONY is only used when i have a file called "all"?

Comment: @ChrisG.: _So PHONY is only used when i have a file called "all"?_ Roughly speaking, yes. But if we look at the details, `.PHONY` also has other side effects. For instance, implicit rules are not searched for declared phony targets (which impacts behaviour and performance).

Comment: @ChrisG.No. Use `.PHONY` for any target that you *intend* to be not-a-file, whether or not there is such a file when you happen to look. That is how you tell `make` to ignore any such file. Bugs or processes not under your control may cause a file of that name to exist at some time and sabotage your build, because you didn't make the target `.PHONY`.